# What is difference between a Data Scientist and a Data Analyst?

Tags: data

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/learn-data-science-infographic
https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/data-engineering-vs-data-science-infographic

These links contain almost everything but not the difference between data science and data analytics.

Is data analytics a part of the data science workflow? Is data analytics a subset of data science?

Comment: Analysts definitely don't write production code but a scientist might. "Data science" is an umbrella term that subsumes data analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please visit [this](https://www.projectpro.io/article/difference-between-data-analyst-and-data-scientist/332) and read the difference between Data analyst and Data scientist.

You will find the above link very interesting that fulfills your need as you will also find the words by Data scientist of LinkedIn.

Important lines from the above link:

> Data analysts are masters in SQL and use regular expression to slice and dice the data. With some level of scientific curiosity data analysts can tell a story from data. A data scientist on the other hand possess all the skills of a data analysts with strong foundation in modelling, analytics, math, statistics and computer science. What differentiates a data scientist from a data analyst is the strong acumen along with the ability to communicate the findings in the form of a story to both IT leaders and business stakeholders in such a way that it can influence the manner in which a company approaches a business challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Those labels are only to create hype, and they aren't well defined, are only nicknames to applied mathematics, statistics or computing. When one is looking a job, stick with the job description, being data analyst, scientist, janitor, caregiver, tamer don't matter overall, which matter is making money with data.

Answer (score 0):

A data analyst discovers patterns in the data using data tools like pandas and sql.  He does not make predictions.  A data scientist measures data distribution and applies statistical methods for looking at data distributions.  The data scientist makes predictions using different classifiers and curve fitting algorithms.